Tensorflow Hub: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_hub' has no attribute 'load'
Got this error message. Used Pycharm IDE for Python.
This is the code I had used:
import tensorflow_hub as hub

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5")

Versions I've got:
tensorflow-hub                   0.16.1
tf-keras                         2.15.0
I've tried to search ways online, but I couldn't find similar error. I think it might be because of the versions, but I didn't try to downgrade the tensorflow. Afraid to mess the situation up even more.
Reinstalled tensorflow and tensorflow_hub with pip install commands. I expected the problem to go away. Didn't help.

pip install --upgrade tensorflow-hub

Other suggestion is to just remove it and reinstall it. It definitely has a 'load'. I just tried it on mine no issue. Other possibilities is you're somehow overwriting "hub" somewhere else.

Thank you @twalow. I have tried pip install --upgrade... command to no luck. The reaction to command is a few statement "Requirement already satisfied". And "no attribute 'load'" error remained.
Your suggestion to uninstall and reinstall it I will leave as a measure of last resort. I uninstalled Numpy once and couldn't even launch my IDE after that.
